# Adding photos from Instragram API to synchronized array in AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire, instagram-api

I built a simple Instagram app using the Instagram API and Angular.

Now I would like to permanently store the users search (aka response from Instagram server for each hashtag entered) to Firebase.

I got the Instagram API call working and saved it as `$scope.instadata` but how do I add `$scope.instadata` to Firebase using `$add()`?

I'm getting err:

> angular.js:11500 Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains a function..

```
var app = angular.module('InstagramApp', ['firebase']);

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http, $firebaseArray) {

  // search posts based on hashtag
  function getHash() {
    var base = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'
    var service = document.getElementById('hashtag').value
    var apiKey = '####'
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    var url = base + service + '/media/recent?access_token=' + apiKey + '&callback=' + callback

    // use jsonp method to prevent CORS error
    $http.jsonp(url).then(function(data) {

        $scope.instadata = data
        console.log("returned json object: ")
        console.log($scope.instadata)

        // set up firebase reference
        var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/fbdata')

        // create a synchronized array 
        $scope.fbdata = $firebaseArray(ref)

        // add new items to the array RETURNS ERROR
        $scope.fbdata.$add($scope.instadata).then(
            function(p){
            console.log(p.key())
            console.log($scope.instadata)
            }, 
            function(err){
            console.log("The expected Firebase action failed to occur this was your error: " + err)
            })  
        }

     })
  }
  document.getElementById('hashtag').addEventListener('click', getHash, false) 
})
```

It's my first time asking a question here, working with API's, Angular and Firebase! I hope that's ok!

Comment: the `data` you receiveback from jsonp contains alot of stuff you probably don't need to add to firebase. Try isolating just what you need from it (in your case probably `data.data`)

Comment: IT WORKED!!! i passed $scope.instadata.data.data --- Thank you so much @RonHarlev ! Have a great weekend :)